# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1-e^{(1+7i)z}}{e^{-z}-1}dz$ as the generalized harmonic number $H_{1+7i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, harmonic-numbers

After I was interested in the entire function that appears in the **Proof** of this **Wikipedia**'s article for [Faulhaber formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), I was asking to [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com), and I've obtained examples as  $$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1-e^{(1+7i)z}}{e^{-z}-1}dz=H_{1+7i},$$

where $H_{z}$ is a **generalized harmonic number**. See it with such example

> integrate (1-e^((1+7i)z))/(e^(-z)-1)dz, from z=-infty to z=0.

I presume that the corresponding generalization should be in the literature,  but

> **Question.** Can you explain us previous example? Why 
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1-e^{(1+7i)z}}{e^{-z}-1}dz=H_{1+7i}?$$ And if it is possible what is  $H_{1+7i}$ (how one defines such harmonic number, from an understandable way). **Thank you for reading my question.**

Comment: Perhaps it is using tricks in integration, now I am confussed. Thanks all users.

Comment: The definition is just a generalization of the well-known 
[formula (2)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)
$H_n = \psi(n+1) + \gamma.$ So $H(1+7i)= \psi(2+7i) + \gamma\approx
2.5448300+1.3593678\times i$

Comment: Then thanks a lot, I'm asking what's about such definition, because it is difficult to me understand what was a generalized harmonic number @gammatester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the more general case $$I=\int  \frac{1-e^{k z}}{e^{-z}-1}\,dz$$ Change variable $z=\log(x)$ and get $$I=\int \frac{x^k-1}{x-1}\,dx$$

This makes $$J=\int_{-\infty}^0  \frac{1-e^{k z}}{e^{-z}-1}\,dz=\int_0^1\frac{x^k-1}{x-1}\,dx=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}x^n\,dx =\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\int_0^1 x^n\,dx= \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac 1{n+1}=H_k$$ This also applies in the complex domain provided $\Re(k)>-1$ .

Comment: Ok, and thanks one more time.

Comment: @user243301. Be sure that you are very welcome. Cheers.